# Is it bad practice to call system() in a shell program?

Tags: c, shell, posix

I'm writing a custom [shell command language interpreter](http://github.com/montao/openshell) and I see that other shells use calls to [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to execute a pipeline or an advanced shell program. Isn't it better to execute a pipeline using `exec` and `fork` instead of making calls to `system()` ? For instance if it is a rescue shell or some other situation then you might not have access to the resource `system()`.

```
/* With the standard output plumbing sorted, execute Nth command */
static void exec_nth_command(int ncmds, char ***cmds) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    if (ncmds > 1) {
        pid_t pid;
        Pipe input;
        if (pipe(input) != 0)
            err_sysexit("Failed to create pipe");
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
            err_sysexit("Failed to fork");
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* Child */
            exec_pipe_command(ncmds - 1, cmds, input);
        }
        /* Fix standard input to read end of pipe */
        dup2(input[0], 0);
        close(input[0]);
        close(input[1]);
    }
    execvp(cmds[ncmds - 1][0], cmds[ncmds - 1]);
    err_sysexit("Failed to exec %s", cmds[ncmds - 1][0]);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

/* Given pipe, plumb it to standard output, then execute Nth command */
static void exec_pipe_command(int ncmds, char ***cmds, Pipe output) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    /* Fix stdout to write end of pipe */
    dup2(output[1], 1);
    close(output[0]);
    close(output[1]);
    exec_nth_command(ncmds, cmds);
}

/* Execute the N commands in the pipeline */
void exec_pipeline(int ncmds, char ***cmds) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_syswarn("Failed to fork");
    if (pid != 0)
        return;
    exec_nth_command(ncmds, cmds);
}
```

As you see from the above code, I never make calls to `system()` in my shell but is it for a good reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are implementing a new shell, using `system(3)` inside would seem strange, because `system(3)` uses the system default shell, which is almost certainly a different shell from the one you're implementing.

Plus, `system(3)` does make certain types of error handling harder--you don't have full visibility into what happened once you launched the child process.

Answer (score 1):

It has its own pros and cons. The implementation very likely call `fork` and `exec` in it, so it is no point to abandon it for the sake of use fork/exec. In fact, if you want to just run a command on the go, does not care of its input/output, exit status etc, a call to `system` would be convenient.

On the other hand, if you want to handle input/output redirections, or have extra fds for the command, or what to get accurate exit status, or send signals to the child process, etc etc, you will need to do fork/exec on your own.

Note that the return value of `system` and the command processor it uses to run the command are all implementation defined, so if you are working on a portable shell, you might want to avoid calling it.

Comment: I just tried my code with FPGA and gcc says the system doesn't have `fork` , so the code didn't even compile for FPGA. But for Linux I think it works to make calls to `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: @Programmer400 What's the system running on the FPGA?

Comment: I got 2 FPGA:s, Altera DE2 and Altera DE2-115. I'm mostly using the DE2 to run C and assembly but I never tried `fork` on FPGA before. The system it runs is a Nios II system with 512K RAM (where I have some different configurations). I can recommend FPGA for C and computer projects. Now for the details of C and operating system FPGA is also good because it's like a computer that runs a custom system. My FPGA can run simple C code but not yet `fork` , although it is stated that the DE2-115 can run uLinux.

Comment: Is `system` available on that system? It would be interesting to see what does it use to run external programs.

Comment: That means that "Nios II" doesn't implement the full POSIX, but only parts of it (or probably none of it). The `system()` itself is not POSIX - it is part of ISO C standard, and thus only specified that it would forward the command to the system shell, whichever that might be.

Comment: `system` does not run the command itself, it invoke the command processor on that system, and invoking the processor is the interesting part here.

Comment: I can try if `system` is available but I'm almost sure it isn't. It can only do "minimal C" and its own assembly (which is similar to MIPS assembly).